# how to install psqlodbc on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to install unixodbc on linux (clean install of ubuntu 20.04), but the directions here (https://odbc.postgresql.org/)
are not working for me. When I get the step to `./configure` , I get an error saying "configure: error: odbc_config not found (required for unixODBC build)".

When I try to install the dependency unixodbc using apt, it says the package doesn't exist. I tried installing it directly from a .deb file which appeared to work with 0 exit status, but I am still getting an error when I try to run `odbc_config`, which is how they say to verify the installation. And `which unixodbc` returns nothing.

Any help installing this package on linux would be greatly appreciated!

Note: On mac, `brew install psqlodbc` works just fine. But I am running into problems when using the compiled binary from that  installation (`psqlodbcw.so`) on a linux machine -- it is giving me a mysterious `file not found` error when I try to reference it, even though it is there, so I believe I need to compile it on linux in order to get it to work.

EDIT: I tried installing unixodbc from source, but then I got a different error: `libpq library version = 9.2 is required`. Is there any way to install this package on ubuntu without having to set all kinds of special flags?

EDIT2: I was able to get the installation process to complete after installing `libpq-dev`. after that, installing psqlodbc from source worked. however, there is no `psqlodbc*.so` -type driver file at the end of the installation, so I still can't use this to make my odbc connection. I made a separate question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154162/where-do-i-find-my-psqlodbc-driver-file-after-installation)

Comment: Your question is extremely hard to follow.  You are missing the instructions that youa re following.  Your title states Ubuntu 18 and in your question you say Ubuntu 20, but you have tagged 20.04.  All three are different versions.  Also, I just followed the exact instructions off of http://www.unixodbc.org/ in the download area and I was able to install unixODBC without any problems in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Please edit and correct your question.

Comment: sorry about that, I just updated it so that the version are correct and match. I'm not sure if maybe you have an older version of odbc_config installed -- but on a clean install of ubuntu 20.04 I get this error.

Comment: You need to install the unixODBC first if you are going to use the unixODBC option with the postgresql install.  I left you the link to install it.  Without installing the unixODBC first it will fail.  Please correct your question that you are trying to install postgresql instead of unixODBC, which appears to be a requirement of the installation that you are trying to do.

Comment: just clarified that I am trying to install both. sorry about the initially confusing post, but ultimately I just want a compiled version of the psqlodbc driver for linux (to use on heroku)